# Kafka Streams - Persist messages by timestamp/sequence?

Tags: java, stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am receiving messages on a Kafka stream. They are keyed by user ID. They are given a sequence number and timestamp when they come in. The messages 'expire' after 15 minutes. User can request new messages based on a given time (up to 15 minutes) or sequence.

What I initially have is something like this:

`
      StreamsBuilder streamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder();

```
  KStream<String, Message> inboundStream = streamsBuilder.stream("incoming.topic");
  messageSupplier = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore("user.messages");

  KTable<String, MessageCache> messageTable = inboundStream
      .filter(this::userExists)
      .peek(this::recordInboundMessage)
      .map(this::markMessage)       // add sequence/timestamp
      .groupByKey()
      .aggregate(this::createMessageCache,
              this::addMessageToMessageCache,
              Materialized.as(messageSupplier));

  // ---> Some other setup stuff, then start the streams
```

`

The `MessageCache` holds the list of messages (removes expired messages when we add the message to the cache). When I get a request for messages, I go through the list and filter out the appropriate messages.

I was thinking I could use one of the windowing strategies, but couldn't find an example that actually persisted a list of messages.

Is this the best way to do this? Or am I missing something that would make this easier/better?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the best way to do this? Or am I missing something that would make this easier/better?

I think you have a simple solution using native java classes that effectively bridges the streams app with your code... There's a lot to be said for simplicity! The only downside I can see is that if your user caches could grow beyond your memory size if your event rate is too high. Also, if you need fault tolerance the streaming app will reconstitute the contents of a state store on another app instance in case of failure. But if that's not a concern, then go for it!

But, in terms of how to do this in a streams app context, there's a few tweaks you could make to do that:

1. Define the granularity of user queries that you want to support. Minutes? Seconds? Let's say minutes for the sake of argument. Window your stream according to that granularity.
2. Define an accumulator, similar to what you have, that will accept a user record and add it to a list. Something like a `UserRecordGroup` that has a `List` of `UserRecord`, and a method `add(UserEvent evt)` that will append a `UserRecord` to the `List`.

Then, you can build your streams app like:

```
KStream<String, Message> inboundStream = streamsBuilder.stream("incoming.topic");
 Materialized<String, UserRecordGroup, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>> userStore =
 Materialized.<String, UserRecordGroup, WindowStore<Bytes,byte[]>>as("user.messages")
  .withValueSerde(/* your serializers here */);


KTable<String, MessageCache> messageTable = inboundStream
  .filter(this::userExists)
  .peek(this::recordInboundMessage)
  .map(this::markMessage)       // add sequence/timestamp
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(ONE_MINUTE_IN_MS))
  .aggregate(UserRecordGroup::new,
            (key, value, agg) -> { agg.add(value); },
             userStore);
```

Finally, when you want to serve queries from the store, you can

```
ReadOnlyWindowStore<Integer, UserRecordGroup> store =
   streams.store("user.messages", QueryableStoreTypes.windowStore());
WindowStoreIterator<UserRecordGroup> windowIterator = 
     store.fetch(pathHash, startTimestamp, endTimeStamp);
```

Your iterator will contain lists of all of the records for the different windows; merge those lists together and you have a description of user activity between startTimestamp and endTimestamp.

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks for the input! In this case, will the older windows just purge themselves, or will they still be there? (Do I have to do something?) Or is that related to the topic's retention config?

Some users will get messages very frequently, some not so much. You made a helpful point that might be multiple app instances. The call for messages is a long pull, so if no messages exist, it waits for a message. I was thinking of notifying the thread when a message came in, but if the call is on a different instance, is there a way to do that?